# Append only last row in a panda dataframe to a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I have the following panda dataframe:(df)

[image]

How can I append only the last row (Date 2021-01-22) to a new dataframe (df_new)?

Comment: check `append` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html

Comment: How can I append only the last row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df_new = df_new.append(df.tail(1))
```

if df_new is not defined. The following code will do it.

```
df_new = df.tail(1)
```

Comment: I am get the following NameError: name 'df_new' is not defined. How do I define df_new?
df_new = pd.DataFrame(last_row) , rigth?

Comment: df_new = df.tail(1) will do the trick.